# Combine 5 List<object> into one List<object>

Tags: c#, list

I have a 5 lists with the same objects in them. I just want to combine them all with there properties intact into one bigger list.

I have thought of a way to do it, but I think there is better ways.

```
List<object> blah = new List<object>

foreach(object item in ObjectList1)
{
   blah.Add(item);
}
```

If you know a better way to do this let me know, Thanks in Advance!

Comment: There must be some libraries in .NET like Guava in Java that can present an aggregated view without actually creating a new list?

Comment: What do you mean by "with all their properties intact"?

Comment: im using .net 4 and I just mean I want the properties to hold the original value, not be reset or reinitialized

Comment: from answers it looks like there are two possibilities depending what exactly are you trying to accomplish. I would be curious which one performs better...

Comment: @BatMasterson adding an object to a collection has no effect on the object's properties; why would you think that it might?

Comment: I didnt know for sure, I just wanted to state it just in case. But thank you for informing me of that =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = ObjectList1.Concat(ObjectList2).Concat(ObjectList3).
                         Concat(ObjectList4).Concat(ObjectList5).ToList()
```

Comment: I think all of the answers are good but this one is the one I ended up using. I up voted all other answers =)~

Comment: How is this answer any different from mine?

Answer (score 6):

You could use either `List<T>.AddRange()` or Linq:

```
foreach(var list in myLists)
   bigList.AddRange(list);
```

Comment: If OP already has a collection of lists, he can simply: `myLists.SelectMany(l => l)`. My understanding was that he has different variables holding the lists.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Enumerable.Concat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx).

```
List<object> blah = ObjectList1
    .Concat(ObjectList2)
    .Concat(ObjectList3)
    // ...
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

This function...

```
static IEnumerable<T> Combine<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] sources) {
    return sources.SelectMany(s => s);
}
```

...can be used like this:

```
List<object> l1 = ... ;
List<object> l2 = ... ;
List<object> l3 = ... ;
List<object> l4 = ... ;
List<object> l5 = ... ;

var result = Combine(l1, l2, l3, l4, l5).ToList();
```

BTW, omit `ToList` if the result doesn't actually need to be a `List`.

*(This will of course work with **any** number of lists, not just 5.)*

---

Or, if you only need to do it once and don't want to introduce a whole new function just for that:

```
var result = new[] { l1, l2, l3, l4, l5 }.SelectMany(l => l).ToList();
```

---

Or, if you care about performance more than readability, do this to avoid memory re-allocations on list resizes:

```
var result = new List<object>(l1.Count + l2.Count + l3.Count + l4.Count + l5.Count);
result.AddRange(l1);
result.AddRange(l2);
result.AddRange(l3);
result.AddRange(l4);
result.AddRange(l5);
```

Answer (score 2):

This code from your question:

```
List<object> blah = new List<object> 

foreach(object item in ObjectList1) 
{ 
   blah.Add(item); 
}
```

... could be more concise if you use `AddRange`:

```
List<object> blah = new List<object> 
blah.AddRange(ObjectList1);
```

So you can either call AddRange 5 times or concat the 5 lists and pass the result to AddRange.

<s>It's not clear what exactly you mean by "with all their properties intact", but if it means that your other lists are lists of *different* more specific types than `object`, then no, you can't create a single list that will give you strongly-typed access to the members of the lists.</s>

**EDIT**

It seems that "with all their properties intact" means that the objects in the new list will have the same property values as the objects in the old list.  And of course they will, since *they are the same objects!*  The lists don't really contain the objects, after all, they contain *references* to the objects (because `object` is a reference type).  The new list contains *copies of the references*, not copies of the objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ObjectList1.Concat(ObjectList2).Concat(ObjectList3).Concat(ObjectList4).Concat(ObjectList5).ToList()`
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to do here. Maybe you should cast the object to a specific object. The code looks correct to me, but it is little weird.

Answer (score 1):

For readability I'd suggest...

```
List<object> blah = new List<object>
blah.AddRange(ObjectList1);
blah.AddRange(ObjectList2);
blah.AddRange(ObjectList3);
blah.AddRange(ObjectList4);
```